# Using attributes as input to db connector

Tags: datastage

In IBM DataStage, we have a connection that involves a Sequence File Connector, a Filter, and a DB2 Lookup stage. Is it possible to perform a DB2 Lookup with information from the Filter stage? For example, if the Filter stage has two records of (age="8") and (age="9"), can we use this information to execute an SQL query on the DB2 connector and retrieve records that satisfy the conditions (age="8") and (age="9")?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is called a [sparse lookup](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.5?topic=ludiod-configuring-sparse-lookup-operations)

The advantage is that the information from the "stream" is used to specifically wquery the database.
On the other hand this could be slow if you are processing many rows - so be thoughtful about this functionality.